# How can I get the p-values from the "dredge" function in R

Tags: model, regression, linear-regression, lm

I want to add the p-values in all the possible combinations between the predictive variables when I use the "dredge" function

I'm gonna use the data from mtcars to replicability

data(mtcars)

I perform a multiple linear reggresion with

```
lm <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars)

##### Then I evaluate all the possible combinations between the models and selected based on AIC
library(MuMIn)
lm_gd <- dredge(lm , rank = "AIC", extra = c("R^2"))
lm_gd
```

What I want is to get the p-value models for every individual model and their combinations, when I print (lm_gd) but I don't find the how to add it in the argument "extra"

Thank you!!